# How to use bisect to search in a compute-when-need array

Tags: python, binary-search

```
bisect.bisect_left((f(x) for x in range(pow(10, 6))), 0)
```

I am trying to use bisect to binary search to the smallest **x** that satisfies **f(x) >= 0**. And f(x) is strictly increasing. The reason I am using binary search is because computing f(x) consumes a lot of resources. So I want to compute it as less as possible.

The problem I encountered here is that the first argument in bisect_left needs to be a list type, which means I have to compute f(x) for every x.

Is there a way to do binary search in this case?

Comment: Sorry, the `bisect` module functions are for working with a list. So you'll have to do your bisection on `x` manually. However, the excellent arbitrary precision `mpmath` module has a [`bisection`](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/optimization.html#mpmath.calculus.optimization.Bisection)-based root solver you may be interested in.

Comment: @PM2Ring You mean code a binary search program by myself?

Comment: Yes, it's not that hard. Give it a go, and if you can't get it working properly post your code here and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Wouldn't `next(x for res, x in ((f(x),x) for x in range(pow(10, 6))) if res > 0)` make a lot more sense?

Comment: @PM2Ring OK. I believe you have encountered the same issue before?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: The OP is trying to avoid a linear search. A binary search over a range of a million should find the solution in less than 20 steps, on average.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think your code compute f(x) from 0 to the first valid x? If that is the case, my situation would not allow me to do that because every computation of f(x) is slow

Comment: @PM2Ring, I understand that, I am talking about in comparison to what they are doing now.

Comment: Looks like you just want the bisect method, not exactly binary search.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yea, but you know binary search and bisect are somewhat the same.

Comment: Yes, it's an extension of binary search for finding the roots of math functions

Comment: @ShadowGiraffe, yes, I was referring to pulling the first as opposed to creating a list and then bisecting unless of course you were repeatedly bisecting the list which I am almost certain you are not.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: ShadowGiraffe was hoping that `bisect` would tell the generator expression to only generate the 20 values needed to perform the bisection and wouldn't generate all million values.

Comment: @PM2Ring, yep and that would be an interesting implementation. I imagine the answer to this question lies in mathematics more than python.

Comment: Thanks @PM2Ring, I just looked into bisect source code, and coded a binary search by myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem I encountered here is that the first argument in bisect_left needs to be a list type

No it doesn't. It needs to be a sequence - a type with a definite length, supporting access by 0-based index. Make a sequence:

```
import collections
class LazySequence(collections.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, f, n):
        """Construct a lazy sequence representing map(f, range(n))"""
        self.f = f
        self.n = n
    def __len__(self):
        return self.n
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if not (0 <= i < self.n):
            raise IndexError
        return self.f(i)
```

Then you can pass one of these to `bisect`:

```
bisect.bisect_left(LazySequence(f, 10**6), 0)
```

Comment: Wow, I am impressed! This is exactly the array I want, compute the value when needed.

Comment: And you can do `0 <= i < n`, I usually do `0 <= i and i < n`, cool!